# Why It never goes in this if (fila.moveToFirst()) line 64

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

```
         package com.pablo.at1.login;

         import android.content.ContentValues;
         import android.database.Cursor;
         import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
         import android.content.Intent;
         import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
         import android.os.Bundle;
         import android.view.View;
         import android.widget.CheckBox;
         import android.widget.EditText;
         import android.widget.Toast;

         public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
             private EditText et1, et2;
             private CheckBox cb1,cb2;

             @Override
             protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                 et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
                 et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
                 cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
                 cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);




             }

             public void Entrar(View view) {

                 if (et1.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0){
                     Toast notificacion=Toast.makeText(this,"El Usuario esta vacio",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                     notificacion.show();
                 }
                 if (et2.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0){
                     Toast notificacion=Toast.makeText(this,"La contraseña esta vacia",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                     notificacion.show();
                 }
                 if (et1.getText().toString()=="Pablo" && et2.getText().toString()=="1111"){

                 }
                 if (!cb1.isChecked()){
                     Toast notificacion=Toast.makeText(this,"Tienes que aceptar la politica de privacidad",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                     notificacion.show();
                 }
                 if (!cb2.isChecked()){
                     Toast notificacion=Toast.makeText(this,"Debes ser mayor de edad",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                     notificacion.show();
                 }
                 if(et1.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && et2.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && cb1.isChecked() &&
 cb2.isChecked()){
                     Intent i = new Intent(this, Menu.class );
                     i.putExtra("direccion", et1.getText().toString());

                     AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,"administrador", null, 1);
                     SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();
                     String usuario = et1.getText().toString();
                     String contrasena = et2.getText().toString();
                     Cursor fila = bd.rawQuery("select * from Usuarios", null);
                    // int id[] = new int[fila.getCount()];
     'HERE IS THE PROBLEM'
                     if (fila.moveToFirst()) {
                        // String contraseña2=fila.getString(0);
                        // if(contrasena==contraseña2){
                         startActivity(i);
                         //}

                     } else
                         Toast.makeText(this, "No existe un Usuario con dicha contraseña",
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     bd.close();
                 }



             }
             public void registrar(View view){
                 if(et1.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && et2.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && cb1.isChecked() &&
 cb2.isChecked()){
                     AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,
                             "administrador", null, 1);
                     SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();
                     String usuario=et1.getText().toString();
                     String contraseña=et2.getText().toString();
                     ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
                     registro.put("usuario", usuario);
                     registro.put("contraseña", contraseña);
                     bd.insert("Usuarios", null, registro);
                     bd.close();
                     et1.setText("");
                     et2.setText("");
                 }

                 if (!cb1.isChecked()){
                     Toast notificacion=Toast.makeText(this,"Tienes que aceptar la politica de privacidad",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                     notificacion.show();
                 }
                 if (!cb2.isChecked()){
                     Toast notificacion=Toast.makeText(this,"Debes ser mayor de edad",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                     notificacion.show();
                 }

             }

         }
```

Comment: Have you checked cursor size?

Comment: There are no line numbers in your example code.

Answer (score 1):

The **`moveToFirst`** method will return false if there are no rows in the Cursor to move to.

Considering that the query will return all columns from all rows from the Usuarios table. The table, which does exist, has no rows.

You could check this by using adding the line

```
Log.d("USUARIOSCNT","Number of rows extracted from the Usuarios table was " + String.valueOf(fila.getCount()));
```

immediately after the line :-
Cursor fila = bd.rawQuery("select * from Usuarios", null);

I can't see that the method `registrar` being called anywhere. I would guess that this is the reason why the table is empty.